# Why does this program segfault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, reverse

Upon compiling and running this small program to reverse a string, I get a Segmentation Fault before any output occurs. Forgive me if this is an obvious question, I'm still very new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int reverse(char string[], int length); 

int main() {
char string[] = "reversed";

  printf("String at start of main = %s", string);
  reverse(string, sizeof(string));
  printf("%s\n", string);

return 0;

}

// Reverse string 
int reverse(char string[], int length) {
 int i;
 char reversed[] = {};
 int temp;

 for(i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
 temp = string[i];
 reversed[length - i] = temp;

 }
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: The code is not compilable as C, since empty `{}` is a syntax error in C. The code is not compilable as C++ either, since it attempts to create a zero-sized array. What language is this supposed to be really?

Comment: @AndreyT - It's suppost to be C.

Comment: @Leda: If this is supposed to be C, then you need to ask your compiler to follow the rules of C language. The `char reversed[] = {}` declaration is not compilable as C language. The compiler is required to point it out.

Comment: @AndreyT: GCC compiled it without any complaints. Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @AndreyT. It is clear Leda has only just begun learning C. Expecting him/her to know the differences between C/C++ standards etc is not reasonable. So I would say the 'C' tag gets precedence over any C++ constructs used in the code. Edit: I see Leda answered the question.

Comment: @Leda: The language the GCC compiler (in its default configuration) passes for C is not really C, but a rather weird mix of rampant extensions with C-like syntax piled up on top of C core. If you want to use C specifically, you need to set up the GCC compiler accordingly. At the very least, you should specify `-ansi -pedantic`  flags when compiling C code.

Comment: @AndreyT: You didn't complain about the `//` comment, which is also not strict C (`-ansi` complains).  Give Leda a break, and help solve the problem rather than splitting hairs.  If gcc requires `-pedantic` to disallow zero-size arrays then I guess its creators don't see it as an important part of the C language.  Clearly, not allocating the memory for `reversed` properly is the answer that will help get the code to work.

Comment: @Paul: Thank you - I've added both those flags to my .vimrc. It now refuses to compile the problematic reversed declaration and // instead of /* for comments. This should save a lot of issues in the future.

Comment: @Paul Stephenson: `//` comments are allowed by C99 standard, so they are compliant with the *current* ANSI C.

Comment: I think there are enough "why does this segfault" questions to warrant creating a new site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of this:

First you create an array with zero elements:

```
char reversed[] = {};
```

And later you attempt to write to that array beyond its bounds:

```
reversed[length - i] = temp;
```

**Update:**

The above means that you need to allocate memory whose size is only known at runtime (it's `length`). The usual C-style way of doing this is... by pushing the burden of memory allocation to your caller:

```
int reverse(const char* string, char* destination, int length);
```

This function would write to a buffer provided by the caller, who now also must ensure that:

1. The buffer is large enough
2. The memory for buffer gets freed when it should be

Comment: @Moron, I think you say my initial post which was wrong. Edited it in the meantime.

Comment: There's no such thing as "array with zero elements" neither in C nor in C++. Moreover, in C there's no such initializer as `{}`. In C at least one expression is always required between the `{}`.

Comment: @AndreyT: you 're correct. It's been ages since the last time I used C or allocated an array on the stack, so I didn't catch that. When saying "zero-length array", I had in mind this: `char* buf = new char[length];` which is legal C++ even if `length` is zero.

Answer (score 3):

While it works in this case, generally , sizeof(string) should be `strlen(string). Usually, when using char pointers, the sizeof operator will just return the size of a single pointer - and not the whole array.
.
In reverse(), Your reverse array is not allocated, you can allocate it like this:

```
char* reversed = (char*) malloc( length+1 );
```

We add one to the length to account for the null char at the end of the string.

Comment: -1: sizeof(string) won't return the size of the pointer. It will return the size of the array in bytes. Try it.

Comment: That's right. I was thinking more of the general case. I've updated my post to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not compilable as C. The declaration

```
char reversed[] = {};
```

is invalid. There's no such thing as empty `{}` initializer in C language (it exists only in C++). Moreover, an empty initializer wouldn't make any sense in an array declaration of unspecified size (which makes this code non-compilable as C++ either), since there's no such thing as zero-sized array neither in C nor in C++.

Either post real code, or retag your question if this is supposed to be C++.

Comment: It is however allowed in gcc -- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html -- and doesn't even give a warning with `-Wall`.

Comment: @Paul Stephenson: What should be a warning and what shouldn't be is always a gray area, but the fact that even `-Wall` does not result in a warning indicates one more time that the default behavior GCC is quite loosely related to real C.

Answer (score 0):

In C you have to think carefully about the memory taken up by your variables and arrays.

When you write `char reversed[] = {}` you are creating a brand-new zero-sized array.  (This is apparently not strictly correct C, but it **is** what is happening with the questioner's gcc compiler.  After all, the report is of a segmentation fault at runtime rather than a syntax error at compile time.)

The statement `reversed[length - i]` then tries to write data to an element of the array you don't have space for, because `reversed` has no size.

You have two options:

- Create a `reversed` array of the proper size (perhaps by using `malloc` as @Bob Kaufman says) *and then return it from the `reverse()` function*.
- Reverse the string "in place", by shifting the characters around within `string` itself.

Reversing the string in place is likely to be preferable -- if you allocate memory dynamically then you have to worry about freeing it again, which can be a pain.

Comment: No, you don't "create brand-new zero-sized array". In C the `{}` initializer is always a syntax error. On top of that zero-sized arrays are always prohibited in C.

Comment: The questioner's code compiles cleanly for me with gcc, and printing `sizeof(reversed)` outputs zero.  Is this a gcc extension?